# How to get the <ul> element of a kendo TimePicker?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How to get the list element of kendoTiemPicker items?
Every kendoTimePicker generates a `<ul>` tag containing all the items that we see in the dropdown of the timepicker. something like this:

```
    <ul tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true" unselectable="on" class="k-list k-reset" style="overflow: auto;">
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" class="k-item" unselectable="on">00:00</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" class="k-item" unselectable="on">01:00</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" class="k-item" unselectable="on">02:00</li>
        <li tabindex="-1" role="option" class="k-item" unselectable="on">03:00</li>
        ...
```

But I have multiple kendoTimePickers in one page, therefore I have multiple lists in page. On the `open event` of one of these timePickers, I want to access the corresponding list of items for **that specific** timePicker. 
Sadly I haven't found anyway to do that. Kendo does not give me a method or property to easily find the list element and so far I was unable to use jquery selectors to access them. 
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.
inside the open event of each timePicker, I can read `e`, and do this:

```
open: function (e) {
           let listContainer = e.sender.timeView.list;
       }
```

and listElement would be a container for the `<ul>` tag I was looking for. 
then I can do this:

```
let listElement = $(listContainer).find('ul');
```

And that's it. It was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the following on Kendo's demo page https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/timepicker/rangeselection

```
$("#start_timeview").find("li").first()
```

And I got the very first available entry of the time picker with the id `start_timeview`. Yesterday, Kendo released a new version which is used on the demo pages. But I'd guess the id is present in older releases as well. If not, try to update first.

Comment: This does not help in my case. This way is very hard-coded and static. in my case the ul tags have no id and I cannot update kendo UI to the latest version.

Comment: What I was hoping to do is to get the same result by using the `$('#timePicker1').data('kendoTimePicker')` and call a method or use a property inside it. So in the `open` event of each timePicker I have the correct list, that belongs to that specific timePicker.